# Gstreamer OpenGL plugin

Tags: opengl, plugins, gstreamer

I've cloned and successfully installed gst-plugins-gl - an OpenGL plugin for Gstreamer (on Ubuntu 12.04, i386), but then I've tried:

gst-launch filesrc location=FORM.MPG ! mpeg2dec ! glimagesink

but "glimagesink" does not exist as an element for gstreamer.

I've tried gst-inspect opengl, but opengl plug-in is absent...

variable GST_PLUGIN_PATH is set to /usr/local/lib/gstreamer-0.10, where I'd copied files:

libgstopengl.la  libgstopengl.so

because initialy they were in /usr/local/lib/gstreamer- (without 0.10)

But it still doesn't work.

gstreamer 0.10 doesn't support gst-register

How can I add new plugin and use it on gstreamer?

Answer (score 0):

How did you build and install them. If they ended up in  /usr/local/lib/gstreamer- (without 0.10) you used some extra parameters in the wrong way. Copying the plugins around won't fix it, as the gl plugin also have a library. Instead you need to fix the way you configured, build and installed them.

Thus go back to your source dir, run sudo make uninstall to cleanup first.
If you want them next to the gstreamer plugins from the packages, do ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr. Leaving the default prefix=/usr/local is fine too, but then you need to set both LD_LIBRARY_PATH and GST_PLUGIN_PATH.